# Firestore reauthenticate user

Tags: firebase, delphi, google-cloud-firestore, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi 10.4.2 and FB4D to do a mobile app.

The first time the user open the app, he create an account (mail / password).

Then he can call Firebase to get documents where he is the owner (settings Firestore rules).

The user can close the app.

When he open it, I didn't want ask him for the password, and I didn't want to store the password on a config file to login him.

I prefer to store a token, and then ask for refresh when it is expired.

When a user is login, I can refresh token like that :

```
if fAuth.NeedTokenRefresh then
   fAuth.RefreshToken(OnTokenRefresh, onUserError);
```

The problem is that the second time he open the app, `FAuth` isn't initialized. Unless I store mail / pwd and login user, what I didn't want to do.

Does it's possible ?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D/wiki/FB4D-Interface-Reference#Interfaces-for-Firebase-Authentication)?

Comment: Yes but I didn't see anything

Comment: *In most applications, you will not call any other Firebase services until you have received an authentication token using the [Firebase Authentication Service](https://github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D/wiki/FB4D-Reference-IFirebaseAuthentication). For a quick and dirty application (e.g. RTDB_SimpleReadWrite of the FB4D Sample Projects), you can also use a service without such an authentication token. In this case, however, you must disable all access rules for Firebase.*

Comment: Disable rules are not a solution :(

Comment: So you must authenticate. This looks like an important feature. The product would be a huge security hole if access cannot be controlled by authentication. Why would you do that?

Comment: Have you tried [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-anonymously)? For example, you could use the anonymous sing in.

Comment: I didn't want anonymous sign in, I want auto authenticate the user when he open the app. I don't want ask for password each time he open it. On Firestore I have rule where user can access to collection / document only if he is login.

Comment: And what about `SignInWithEmailAndPasswordSynchronous`? You can store the user email and password in some local storage. The user don't have to see that.

Comment: Yep for sure, but in term of security I didn't wanted to store it, but I didn't any other solution. I will need to do it I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone have same question, you can login a user with the last refresh token you get :

```
FraSelfRegistration.Initialize(FConfig.Auth, OnUserLogin, 'last_token');
```

You need to add the uses `FB4D.SelfRegistrationFra` and init `FConfig` like that :

```
FConfig := TFirebaseConfiguration.Create(ApiKey, ProjectID, '', FirebaseURL);
```

So you can login user without store any password

Answer (score 0):

Never save the user's email and password in your app!
I do this in the demo application only to accelerate the first step in learning firebase/FB4D.

Instead, save the RefreshToken as implemented in the self-registration frame.

Good success with FB4D!